# Fixed header and sidebar with scrollable content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a layout with flexbox that has a fixed header and sidebar, and a scrollable content in the main panel. The sidebar is expected to be shown above the content on smaller screens, which works fine. I have managed to make the header sticky, but I'm not sure how to make the sidebar stick and while still being able to scroll the content.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #ffccaa;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: #ccaaff;
  flex-basis: 10rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#content {
  background-color: #ccffaa;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 999;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <p>navbar</p>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <p>sidebar</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel tellus non nulla aliquet mollis sit amet a eros. Quisque nec lacus ligula. Sed nec risus feugiat enim ultrices venenatis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec elementum, nibh vel scelerisque aliquam, est ipsum faucibus ipsum, eget molestie felis risus non enim. Sed vulputate, odio a rutrum condimentum, massa justo fringilla nibh, nec cursus nunc purus molestie risus. Maecenas imperdiet non odio at maximus. Nullam luctus rutrum fermentum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel tellus non nulla aliquet mollis sit amet a eros. Quisque nec lacus ligula. Sed nec risus feugiat enim ultrices venenatis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec elementum, nibh vel scelerisque aliquam, est ipsum faucibus ipsum, eget molestie felis risus non enim. Sed vulputate, odio a rutrum condimentum, massa justo fringilla nibh, nec cursus nunc purus molestie risus. Maecenas imperdiet non odio at maximus. Nullam luctus rutrum fermentum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel tellus non nulla aliquet mollis sit amet a eros. Quisque nec lacus ligula. Sed nec risus feugiat enim ultrices venenatis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec elementum, nibh vel scelerisque aliquam, est ipsum faucibus ipsum, eget molestie felis risus non enim. Sed vulputate, odio a rutrum condimentum, massa justo fringilla nibh, nec cursus nunc purus molestie risus. Maecenas imperdiet non odio at maximus. Nullam luctus rutrum fermentum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel tellus non nulla aliquet mollis sit amet a eros. Quisque nec lacus ligula. Sed nec risus feugiat enim ultrices venenatis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec elementum, nibh vel scelerisque aliquam, est ipsum faucibus ipsum, eget molestie felis risus non enim. Sed vulputate, odio a rutrum condimentum, massa justo fringilla nibh, nec cursus nunc purus molestie risus. Maecenas imperdiet non odio at maximus. Nullam luctus rutrum fermentum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can try using media queries with a `max-width` property to add a position `sticky` to your sidebar

Answer (score 1):

Define a height on either the header or the wrapper, and then it can work.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):

> In order for `overflow` to have an effect, the block-level container
> must have either a set height (`height` or `max-height`) or
> `white-space` set to `nowrap`.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;  /* overrides default margin */
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #ffccaa;
  flex: 0 0 50px; /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px); /* height of body less height of navbar */
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: #ccaaff;
  flex-basis: 10rem;
}

#content {
  background-color: #ccffaa;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto; /* triggers scrollbar */
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <p>navbar</p>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <p>sidebar</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel tellus non nulla aliquet mollis sit amet a eros. Quisque nec lacus ligula. Sed nec risus feugiat enim ultrices venenatis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec elementum, nibh vel scelerisque aliquam, est ipsum faucibus ipsum, eget molestie felis risus non enim. Sed vulputate, odio a rutrum condimentum, massa justo fringilla nibh, nec cursus nunc purus molestie risus. Maecenas imperdiet non odio at maximus. Nullam luctus rutrum fermentum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel tellus non nulla aliquet mollis sit amet a eros. Quisque nec lacus ligula. Sed nec risus feugiat enim ultrices venenatis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec elementum, nibh vel scelerisque aliquam, est ipsum faucibus ipsum, eget molestie felis risus non enim. Sed vulputate, odio a rutrum condimentum, massa justo fringilla nibh, nec cursus nunc purus molestie risus. Maecenas imperdiet non odio at maximus. Nullam luctus rutrum fermentum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel tellus non nulla aliquet mollis sit amet a eros. Quisque nec lacus ligula. Sed nec risus feugiat enim ultrices venenatis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec elementum, nibh vel scelerisque aliquam, est ipsum faucibus ipsum, eget molestie felis risus non enim. Sed vulputate, odio a rutrum condimentum, massa justo fringilla nibh, nec cursus nunc purus molestie risus. Maecenas imperdiet non odio at maximus. Nullam luctus rutrum fermentum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel tellus non nulla aliquet mollis sit amet a eros. Quisque nec lacus ligula. Sed nec risus feugiat enim ultrices venenatis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec elementum, nibh vel scelerisque aliquam, est ipsum faucibus ipsum, eget molestie felis risus non enim. Sed vulputate, odio a rutrum condimentum, massa justo fringilla nibh, nec cursus nunc purus molestie risus. Maecenas imperdiet non odio at maximus. Nullam luctus rutrum fermentum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vn5f8zwh/)